# Openany still producing extra page

Tags: double-sided, books, opentype

I am very close to completing my project, but I am not sure why `openany` for my chapters is producing an extra page on pg.viii. I thought `openany` would fix where I could place the beginning of my chapters, but it is not working as desired.

The goal is to get the full size images on the odd page and the even page opposite the image would be the chapter beginning. So, remove the extra page viii and make it to where all chapters (levels) begin with image on left and chapter wording on right.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, xcolor, wrapfig, float, enumitem, xcoffins, atbegshi, fontspec, etoolbox, multicol}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\setmainfont{Futura}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
   \markright{\thechapter\ #1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{style3}{
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{style1}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{BLUE}{HTML}{23afdc}
\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{a81e2d}
\definecolor{ORANGE}{HTML}{ea6d3c}
\definecolor{YELLOW}{HTML}{e6a327}
\definecolor{GREEN}{HTML}{5fa244}
\definecolor{INDIGO}{HTML}{005988}
\definecolor{VIOLET}{HTML}{7B2C8E}

%\usepackage[bidi=bidi-l,english]{babel}
%\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}

%\babelfont{rm}{Futura}
%\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{DejaVu Sans}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Codex: Anthromancer \\ \vspace{20pt} {\large Contains rules for the Mercenarium Arcade, \\ a guide to Dragonfruit Alchemy,\\ and information for the Hymnal Protocol. \\}}
\author{Tetra Entertainment}
\date{April 2020 \\ \vspace{20pt} {\scriptsize \textcolor{gray}{U.S. Patent no. 10,765,931}}}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

this is the second table of contents page.

\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\pagestyle{style1}

\newgeometry{top=0in, right=1in, left=1in, bottom=1in}

\chapter{Introduction: A Human Experience.}

\vspace{-1cm}

\textit{hu·man (adj.): relating to or characteristic of people or human beings; as opposed to God or animals or machines, especially in being susceptible to weakness; or, characteristic of people’s better qualities, such as kindness or sensitivity.}\\

What does it mean to be human?\\

When an algorithm can diagnose disease better than the most experienced doctors, defeat the greatest players of abstract strategy games, and generate art as beautifully as our most virtuosic creative minds, this question takes on a new significance. What makes us different?\\

We’re at an important moment in our story. The choices we make today will have a profound impact on the world of tomorrow. Let us hold space for humanity to pause and reflect on where we’ve been, to better understand where we’re going.\\

This codex, and the deck, dice, and board that come with it, are intended as a celebration of human heritage. This celebration is expressed through four levels: as games, as an oracle, as an album of songs, and as a story. Each level is explained through a section in this book, prefaced by a brief exploration of its cultural context. Care has been taken to ensure that each level is self-contained while also serving to add depth to the others. Explore them on your own terms.\\

We hope you find joy here. We hope to give you an opportunity to see things in a new way. Mostly we hope to tell a new story, one in which love for the world is enough to transform it. With your participation these intentions will spring to life, carried in your head and your heart as we step forward into the unknown. \\

This is Anthromancer.\\

Be Moved.\\

\restoregeometry
\clearpage

\section{The 4 Levels of Anthromancer}
%\chaptermark{OVERVIEW: THE 4 LEVELS OF ANTHROMANCER}

\raisebox{4in}{\begin{tabular}{p{0.75in} p{4.5in}}
{\bf Level 1:} & The Mercenarium Arcade – A suite of competitive games emphasizing logic, chance, and skill. (p.1)\\
 & \\
{\bf Level 2:} & Dragonfruit Alchemy – An oracle based upon the meanings of the classical elements. (p.25)\\
& \\
{\bf Level 3:} & The Hymnal Protocol – A reference text containing the rules, meanings, and lyrics of the Hymns. (p.58)\\
& \\
{\bf Level 4:} & The Fool and The Fox – A mythological account of Anthromancer’s essence. (p.90)\\
\end{tabular}}

\restoregeometry
\pagebreak

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\hspace*{-0.3125in}\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-b}
\caption{Product photo: Contents of Anthromancer}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

Your box should include:

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item (1) Anthromancer board
\item (71)-card Anthromancer deck
\item (3) dice, comprised of (2) 6-sided Fool and Fox dice and (1) 12-sided Zodiac die.
\item (4) quick reference cards
%\item[--] (1) quick start guide
\item (1) Anthromancer Codex (this book)
\end{itemize}

If any of these components are missing, please contact \href{mailto:help@anthromancer.com}{help@anthromancer.com}.

\clearpage

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{style1}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%********Start on odd page
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

%*********Start on even page
\chapter{LEVEL 1: The Mercenarium Arcade}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LEVEL 1: The Mercenarium Arcade}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}} 

\textit{Game  (n.): A form of play or sport, especially a competitive one, played according to rules and dictated by skill, strength or luck.}\\

The oldest known board game was played in the first dynasty of Egypt more than five thousand years ago. It was called Senet, and it’s unclear if we still remember how to play it. Nevertheless, its antiquity speaks to the importance games hold in human culture. The Royal Game of Ur, Mancala, Go, Chess...while these may not be quite as venerable as Senet, they’ve been passed down for hundreds or thousands of years, transcending their designers and becoming a part of our collective heritage. Great games have been played by monarchs and mendicants, in taverns and temples; brought camaraderie to some and bitter rivalry to others. They have shaped the course of history in ways we may never know.\\

There is power here. Games challenge us to better ourselves. They generate flow, happiness, and wonder, or else get under our skin and drive us to obsession. They fascinate us.\\

The Mercenarium Arcade was designed with these ideas in mind. It is an evolution of artifacts that have enchanted us since time immemorial, a synthesis of the board, the tile, the die, the deck, and the magic of chance. It invites you to conquer the odds no matter what you’re dealt. Most importantly…it’s fun.\\

Welcome to the the Mercenarium Arcade.

\pagebreak

\section{What is the Mercenarium Arcade?}

Mercenarium is Anthromancer’s original game of strategy and chance, but a collection of variants and other new games can be played with the same components. This collection is referred to as the Mercenarium Arcade:

\section*{Mercenarium (p.4)}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Players: 2--4
\item Time: 30 minutes
\item Genre: Abstract Strategy/Chance
\end{itemize}

Mercenarium is an abstract strategy game with a neoclassical aesthetic. Players take turns placing and moving cards around the board to try and overcome the pip values on the edges of their opponent’s cards. Players compete to be the first to (5) captures, or to eliminate their opponents by blocking their houses. Face cards on the board (J, Q, K, or A) are called Mercenaries and can be ‘bought’ by an opponent with an unspent capture to subvert strategies, while hymn cards offer unique powers that alter the flow of the game in surprising and dramatic ways. Mercenarium rewards strategic thinking and the luck of the draw in equal measure.\\

\textbf{Variants: High, Classic, Mad (p.15)}\\

\section*{Zealot (p.17)} 

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Players: 2 or more
\item Time: 20 minutes or more
\item Genre: Speed/Pattern recognition
\end{itemize}

Zealot is a twist on Rat Screw, a classic card-capturing and pattern recognition game. The deck is divided evenly between all players, who then take turns drawing cards from their own piles and placing them face-up on a central pile. When courts or hymns appear, the next player in rotation has between 1 and 5 chances to beat the previous card depending upon its value. If they succeed, play continues to the next player; if they fail, the previous player takes the pile. When certain patterns appear in the pile, the first player to ‘slap’ the pile with their hand takes the pile. The objective is to take possession of all cards in the deck. Wear rings for additional pain.\\

\section*{Solitarium (p.20)}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Players: 1
\item Time: 20 minutes
\item Genre: Solitaire
\end{itemize}

Solitarium is an original solitaire. The player places a 5x5 tableau of cards face-up and attempts to find pip matches between adjacent cards to remove those cards from play. When a Hymn is matched (which matches based on shape and color instead of pips), the player keeps it, and may discard it later in order to rotate a card in the tableau or sweep cards into empty spaces. The objective is to clear the deck using as few hymns as possible. The number of hymns held at the end of the game determines the player’s score.
\end{document}
```

Comment: \mainmatter does a \cleardoublepage, as it resets the page number to 1 and so tries hard to start an odd page.

Comment: Any way to undo this?

Comment: why do you write there \mainmatter if you don't want it? Move it before the real chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Change what is between `If any of these components are missing`  and `\setcounter{figure}{0}` for this code

```
If any of these components are missing, please contact \href{mailto:help@anthromancer.com}{help@anthromancer.com}.

%%  from here
\clearpage \thispagestyle{empty} % even side of previous page

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}    

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{style1}

\chapter{LEVEL 1: The Mercenarium Arcade}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LEVEL 1: The Mercenarium Arcade}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%% to here
    
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```

[image: c]

"All chapters (levels) will begin with the image on the left (even pages) and the chapter wording on the right (odd pages)."

I understand that means with the book open, as shown in the figure.

To do this, if the previous chapter ends on an even page, you will need to add a double blank  page  to insert the figure on its even side,  to maintain the style.

[image: F]

For example, changing the code before the figure to

```
%%  from here
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty} %<<<<<  even side of previous page
\mbox{}                       % <<<  for an empty odd page
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty} %  even side of previous page
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}    

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{style1}
\chapter{LEVEL 1: The Mercenarium Arcade}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LEVEL 1: The Mercenarium Arcade}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%% to here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `memoir` documentclass ( a superset of `book`, `report` and `article`) and its `\movetoevenpage` macro.

```
% chapterprob.tex  SE 583508

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\movetoevenpage%[Your figure]
YOUR FIGURE
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\movetoevenpage%[Another figure]
ANOTHER FIGURE
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This moves to an even (verso) page, typesets on that page and then calls `\chapter` which will be typeset on the following recto page, so that your illustration will be typeset on the (even) page preceding the chapter title (on the odd page).